# Is the fundamental lemma of Calculus of Variations wrong?

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

the title might be a bit absurd but this is how I currently feel just because I can't see where my reasoning is faulty.

So the lecturer presented the lemma as the following:

Let $M \in C[a, b]$. Then $\int_{a}^{b} M \cdot h \,dx = 0, \forall h \in C_0^1[a,b] \implies M \equiv 0$.

But how does the lemma still hold when $h(x) = 0$? The integral would still be zero but it would not imply that $M = 0$ since it could for example be $M = x$. Am I wrong to believe that $0 \in C_0^1[a,b]$?

He gives a proof by contradiction using a non-zero $h$ (the bump function ) somewhere in the lines of: Say $M$ is greater than zero and $h$ is greater than zero, then the integral must also be greater than zero which results in a contradiction since the integral must be equal to zero. Therefore $M$ must be zero. This is obviously true for the case when $h$ is non-zero but isn't this an obvious loss of generality? When $h$ is also allowed to be zero then one can not easily deduce which function is making the integral to be zero. If the lemma would require that it applies to $\forall h \in \{C_0^1[a,b] \setminus 0\}$ then everything would make sense but that is not how the lemma is generally expressed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The hypothesis is that **for all** $h\in C_0^1$ we have $\int_a^b Mh=0$, not just for one $h$

Comment: Indeed, for any *one* function $h$ whose integral is nonzero, you can always find a function $M$ with $\int M \cdot h$ being zero: take $M(x) = h(x) - C$, where $C$ is just $$\frac{\int_a^b h^2(x) dx}{ \int_a^b h(x) dx}.$$ You can probably work out something similar in the case where $\int_a^b h(x) dx = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be reading it as$$\color{red}{\forall h\in C_0^1[a,\,b]\left(\int_a^bMhdx=0\implies M=0\right)},$$but it actually means$$\color{limegreen}{\left[\forall h\in C_0^1[a,\,b]\left(\int_a^bMhdx=0\right)\right]\implies M=0.}$$It's the equivalent of confusing$$\color{limegreen}{\text{If all people like me, I'm popular}}$$with$$\color{red}{\text{If you pick any one person, if they like me I'm popular}}.$$

Comment: Yes exactly, couldn't be stated better. My aha moment was in a comment under an other answer but that sums it perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The question “how does the lemma still hold when $h(x)=0$?” makes no sense, since the hypothesis is that the equality $\int_a^bM\times h=0$ for **every** compactly supported smooth function.

Comment: Well that is what many are pointing out, including my professor, that it is **for every/all**. I just don't understand what is meant by that. How can it be **for every** if there exists one example where this is not the case because then it is clearly not for every.

Comment: The assertion is the *if* the equality $\int_a^bM\times h=0$ holds for **every** compactly supported smooth function $h$, *then* $M=0$. Checking that $\int_a^bM\times h=0$ for **one** function $h$ (namely, the null function) is very far from being the same thing as checking that $\int_a^bM\times h=0$ for **every** function $h$

Comment: It's like saying that a function $f\colon\Bbb R\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ is continuous at $0$ if, for every sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, you also have $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=f(0)$. Approaching this the way you approached the fundamental lemma of calculus of variations, you could say that every function $f$ is continuous at $0$, since, if $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is the null sequence, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=f(0)$.

Comment: Oookay, I think I got it from the second comment. That **for every** means **for every at the same time** and not **here all all** pick one, that is obviously the difference between the there exists symbol and the for all symbol. I feel so stupid now haha but thank you so much for the help!